ggplot2::geom_smooth() drops aesethetics "label" with {ggrepel}
I want to use ggplot2::geom_smooth() together with the {ggrepel} package, but I always get a warning. See the following Reprex with the Anscombe dataset:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
anscombe |>
    ggplot(
        aes(
            x = x3,
            y = y3,
            label = rownames(anscombe)
        )
    ) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(
        formula = y ~ x,
        se = FALSE,
        method = "lm"
    ) +
    geom_text_repel()
#> Warning: The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: label.
#> ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in
#>   the data.
#> ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical
#>   variable into a factor?


Created on 2024-05-29 with reprex v2.1.0
How to get rid of this warning?

The "label" aesthetic isn't 'understood' by geom_smooth(), e.g.

So, if you insert "label" in geom_text_repel(), or if you don't pass the label aesthetic to geom_smooth(), you shouldn't get the warning:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
anscombe |>
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = x3,
      y = y3
      )
    ) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(
    formula = y ~ x,
    se = FALSE,
    method = "lm"
    ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(
      label = rownames(anscombe)
      )
    )



anscombe |>
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = x3,
      y = y3,
      label = rownames(anscombe)
    )
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(
    aes(
      x = x3,
      y = y3
    ),
    formula = y ~ x,
    se = FALSE,
    method = "lm",
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_text_repel()


Created on 2024-05-30 with reprex v2.1.0

Your second example was especially important for my understanding. But I saw in many {ggrepel} examples the use of "label" in the first ggplot-aes call (for instance: "label = car" in https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html#hide-some-of-the-labels.) without  "inherit.aes = FALSE". How is that possible?

The warning is caused by passing the label aesthetic from ggplot() to geom_smooth(); if you use other geoms, like in the example you linked, you won't get the warning. Does that make sense?

It does not make sense to me because {ggplot2} still does not understand the "label" aesthetics. But I can live with it ;-)

Sorry if I didn't explain it  clearly; this is an 'edge case' and it's not intuitive. The ggplot2 book explains in detail the design choices and subsequent implications - especially the chapter on 'internals' - if you're interested and want to understand what's going on it's worth a read (free online: https://ggplot2-book.org/ ; purchase: https://www.amazon.com/ggplot2-Elegant-Graphics-Data-Analysis/dp/331924275X)
